# Subtraction of combinations

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm aware of the Pascal's Identity which we use it for solving question but I'm looking for an identity for substracting combinations . For example how we can rewrite $C(n, k+1) - C(n , k)$?

**Note** : Honestly , I was solving a problem and then I get to this .

Comment: what was the problem ?  what has been tried? I could actually use this math in some of my attempted Lucas-Lehmer test questions for example.   the first is how many times the second ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee It's the problem : $C(n,4) = 14 + C(n,3)$ Now find $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Comment: again I'll tell you find there ratio first.

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: what is the formula for n choose k.

Comment: $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63069/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-s-h-w).